# Please help me for where condition with inner join giving error too fer parameters. expected 2

Tags: ms-access-2010

here  creditbills is a table which inner joined with partymaster table.

this is perfect

but now i want to add where condition which filter the data between from date & to date from billprint (form) put by user

but it is giving error too fer parameters. expected 2.

i think this code need some parentheses but i am very new in this

please help me out from this code.

```
strSql1 = "SELECT DISTINCT [CreditBills.PartyName],[CreditBills.Date],[PartyMaster.EMAILTO],[PartyMaster.EMAILCC]" & _
      "FROM [PartyMaster]INNER JOIN [CreditBills] ON [CreditBills].[PartyName] = [PartyMaster].[PartyName]" & _
      "WHERE [CreditBills.Date]Between[Forms]![BillPrint]![FromDt] And [Forms]![BillPrint]![ToDt]"
```

Comment: Make sure you have space between keywords properly e.g. `FROM [PartyMaster]INNER JOIN` has no space between table name and keyword.

Answer (score 2):

A few things I noticed, you have enclosed the Table Name and Field name in between one set of Square brackets. Then you have spacing issues. Finally, you need to make sure that the Arguments are concatenated to the SQL String. Not simply used as one would with a Query using a Query design.

Try this,

```
strSql1 = "SELECT DISTINCT [CreditBills].[PartyName], [CreditBills].[Date], " & _
          "[PartyMaster].[EMAILTO], [PartyMaster].[EMAILCC] FROM [PartyMaster] " & _
          "INNER JOIN [CreditBills] ON [CreditBills].[PartyName] = [PartyMaster].[PartyName] " & _
          "WHERE [CreditBills].[Date] Between " & Format([Forms]![BillPrint]![FromDt], "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & _
          "And " & Format([Forms]![BillPrint]![ToDt], "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")
```

Comment: Dear sir please explain  "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#" this past of the format function. now i am getting error "item not found in collection"

Comment: Access treats all dates in American Format, even if you enter the right format based on the regional settings. So Format function makes sure the dates are etered in the right format. Item not found in collection is not related to this line of code is it? To answer that you need to tell us where it happens.